# Assets is outputing strange file paths

Tags: assets, wygwam

When I link a file in a WYGWAM field, the link seems to be created correclty. If I look at the source of the HTML, the link is displayed as,

```
<a href="/uploads/documents/campus_map.pdf">File</a>
```

If I look at the DB for that field, it is saved as,

```
<a href="{assets_25:{filedir_2}campus_map.pdf}">File</a>
```

However when the template is parsed, the final output is,

```
<a href="/uploads/documents/campus_map.pdfcampus_map.pdf}">File</a>
```

If I manually remove the "{filedir_2}" from the DB record, everything works fine and the output is,

```
<a href="/uploads/documents/campus_map.pdf">File</a>
```

I'm using all the latest versions,

1. EE 2.6.1
2. Assets 2.1.4
3. Wygwam 2.7.1
4. Structure 3.3.10

Thanks for any help you guys can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've got a fix for this locally that will be in the next release of Wygwam.  In the meantime, hit up support@pixelandtonic.com and we can send you the patched files.

Comment: Great, my client will be very happy to hear that, thanks!